# Kotlin @Value dosen't set variables spingboot security

Tags: kotlin, spring-security, environment-variables

trying to set some parameters in the `AuthenticationManager` of `SpringBootSecurity` by getting values from `application.properties`, but the values are only the one set by default, and not the one in the application.properties file

Have used `@Value` in other places of my app without problem, but in this class somenthing is wrong...
whatever I set in `application.properties`, the values are always the default ones.
e.g `refreshTokenExpiredDays` should be 4 (see `applicationproperties` file below) but in fact it is 1

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value
class ApplicationAuthenticationFilters(
          authenticationManager: AuthenticationManager
    ):UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter(authenticationManager) {
    
        @Value("\${security-json-token-secret}")
        private val jsonTokenSecret: String = "secret"
    
        @Value("\${security-access-token-expired-mns}")
        private val accessTokenExpiredMns: Int = 10
    
        @Value("\${security-refresh-token-expired-days}")
        private val refreshTokenExpiredDays: Int = 1
    
        @Value("\${security-tokens-in-header}")
        private val tokensInHeader: Boolean=false

    ...
    ...}
```

**application.properties**

```
cors-origin-patterns=http://localhost:3000,https://localhost,http://localhost:8080

security-json-token-secret=secret
security-access-token-expired-mns=20
security-refresh-token-expired-days=4
security-tokens-in-header=true
```

**[EDIT]** wondering why someone set -1 to my question...
BTW, yes, this filter class is called when overriding the configure function in the WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter

```
override fun configure(http: HttpSecurity) {

        val applicationAuthenticationFilter:ApplicationAuthenticationFilters = ApplicationAuthenticationFilters(authenticationManagerBean())

    applicationAuthenticationFilter.setFilterProcessesUrl("/auth/login")

    http.csrf().disable();
    http.sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
    http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/auth/login/**", "/auth/token/refresh/**").permitAll();
    http.authorizeRequests().anyRequest().authenticated()
    // filtre ici pour gérer la JWT vai authentificationManager
    http.addFilter(applicationAuthenticationFilter)
}
```

**[EDIT 2] My solution**
Finaly have created a data class that I inject in all constructors that require a variable from `application.properties`

```
@Component
data class EnvVariables(
    @Value("\${security-json-token-secret}")
    val jsonTokenSecret: String = "secret",

    @Value("\${security-access-token-expired-mns}")
    val accessTokenExpiredMns: Int = 10,

    @Value("\${security-refresh-token-expired-days}")
    val refreshTokenExpiredDays: Int = 1,


    @Value("\${security-tokens-in-header}")
    val tokensInHeader: Boolean = false
)
```

Comment: how are you initialising and using  `ApplicationAuthenticationFilters `? Are you calling the constructor explicitly?

Answer (score 1):

You can do the following:

```kotlin
@Value("\${security-json-token-secret:secret}")
lateinit var jsonTokenSecret: String

@Value("\${security-access-token-expired-mns:10}")
lateinit var accessTokenExpiredMns: Int

@Value("\${security-refresh-token-expired-days:1}")
lateinit var refreshTokenExpiredDays: Int
    
@Value("\${security-tokens-in-header: false}")
lateinit var tokensInHeader: Boolean
```

**Note:** Your class (filter or otherwise) will need to be an `@Bean` or `@Component` in order to have values injected into them. In your **[EDIT]** it appears you are constructing it manually, in which case your properties will not be handled by Spring.

Additionally, other techniques exist instead of `@Value`, such as using `@ConfigurationProperties`.

Comment: finally I went for a dedicated data class in Kotlin, marked as @Component where I gather and collect all varaibles from application.properties, class that I inject in several constructors.